Как установить Gnome в Debian под WSL и подключиться к нему?
Установил в Debian под WSL окружение GNOME и запустил xrdp, но при подключении через Удалённый рабочий стол Windows после ввода логина и пароля проходит несколько секунд, после чего окно просто закрывается.
